# If condition with boolean function call is always True in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have written a program and at the end I have written a code for the user to rate my program, but it has some issues please help:

```
while True:
    RR = input("What would you rate this program(?/5): ")
    if RR.isnumeric:
        rating = int(RR)
        if rating >= 5:
            print("Looks like you are highly satisfied with this program :D")
            break
        elif rating == 4 or rating == 3:
            print("Ohh! Next time I'll try my best to change this '",rating,"' into 5 ;D")
            break
        elif rating == 1 or rating == 2:
            print("I am sorry if I wasn't good, I'll try my best next time :|")
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid Rating, Try again...")
        continue
```

Result

```
What would you rate this program(?/5): g
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
```

What I want is that if someone enters a text instead of a number then it tells that it's an invalid input and continues the loop. How can I get this?

Comment: ``str.isnumeric`` is a function. ``str.isnumeric`` is always ``True`` as it checks if it is a truthy value and function object are always truthy. You want to add the ``()`` to actually execute the function. Fixed: ``if RR.isnumeric():``

Comment: Ahh so the easter egg is that you can bypass the rating system by entering any negative integer or zero!  Good to know.  Personally, I'd just delete any program that asked me this question and save the hassle ;)

Comment: @paddy Actually, if you input 0, it will just loop again without printing anything, and a negative will not be "numeric".

Comment: Thanks everyone I changed my code and now it's working properly Thank You :D

Comment: @MuavizMushtaqShah you should accept an answer by clicking the checkmark/tick below the up/downvote buttons on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is not a function call, but rather a reference to the function. It is not yet called.

It should be `if RR.isnumeric()` not `if RR.isnumeric`.

Comment: Thanks I changed my code and now it's working properly Thank You :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems.

1. Your if condition checks `str(RR).isnumeric` which is always True, since that function exists for all string objects. Change it to `RR.isnumeric()`.
2. In your inner if you might want to put in an `else:contine` to not bypass the voting system, when a value smaller than 1 is entered.

Here's code that should do what you want:

```
while True:
    RR = input("What would you rate this program(?/5): ")
    if RR.isnumeric():
        rating = int(RR)
        if rating >= 5:
            print("Looks like you are highly satisfied with this program :D")
            break
        elif rating in [3, 4]:
            print("Ohh! Next time I'll try my best to change this '",rating,"' into 5 ;D")
            break
        elif rating in [1, 2]:
            print("I am sorry if I wasn't good, I'll try my best next time :|")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Rating, Try again...\nPlease enter a value from 1 to 5")
    else:
        print("Invalid Rating, Try again...\nPlease enter a value from 1 to 5")
```

You should tell the user what they should do imo, and you don't need a `continue` in a `while True` if you don't need to skip any code anyway. Also a list comparison to check if your rating is within a set of numbers is nicer to read. Another very enjoyable way to compare ranges in Python is like this:

```
if 0 < x < 7:
    pass
elif 6 < x < 10:
    pass
```

But for small ranges like in your case, I prefer using lists.

HTH

Comment: Thanks I changed my code and now it's working properly Thank You :D

Comment: If it worked, make sure to accept my answer :) I also added an example of comparison operator chaining, which you might yet know about ;)